# Set query timeout in milliseconds, not seconds, on invocation of PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, oracle11g, timeout

Is there a way to set the query timeout in milliseconds, instead of seconds? The java.sql.Statement API only has a method for seconds, but even 1 second is too slow for my use case.

Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)

I am using the Oracle DB.

Comment: Just curious: what is this use case?

Comment: Low latency service dealing with high volumes of data.

Comment: And how would you handle the timeout event?

Comment: Ignore that particular query, and continue. I'm only concerned with the data I can get back in a reasonable amount of time, anything greater means its useless data. 

And I'm working on other items to reduce making expensive queries in the first place. This is just one step of many.

Comment: Just had an idea, it is not "clean and simple", but might help. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite convoluted, but *could* work:

1. have an ExecutorService
2. create a Callable for the query
3. submit the callable to ExecutorService
4. the `Future<ResultType>` will have a "[get(Long, TimeUnit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)" function, blocking until at most the set timeout - which has configurable granularity (at least it promises to be like that...

Something like this in almost-Java-code:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<ResultType> {
  @Override
  public ResultType call() throws Exception {
    //do query, with 1s timeout - that way no thread will be busy for more than 1s
    return result;
  }
}
```

Handling the requests

```
ExecutorService threadPool; //initialised somewhere earlier

Future<ResultType> futureResult = threadPool.submit(new MyCallable());
try {
    ResultType result = futureResult.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //results received in time, do the processing here
} catch(TimeoutException e) {
    //request too slow -- handle it
} catch( other exceptions...) { ... }
```

#### Concerns:

- I don't know how much overhead this means...
- timeout: I don't know how exactly will they be handled.
- the requests that time out, will be stuck in the threadpool until the inner, JDBC timeout (1s) kicks in...
- threadpool: if fixed, might be a bottleneck (see concern above), if dynamic: might be an overhead

Comment: This is essentially what I decided to do. The bottleneck is still a concern, but should be alleviated once I've implemented the other ways to reduce the number of expensive queries made.

Comment: This won't work for the `Transaction` way since the Callable is a different thread :(

Answer (score 0):

I realise this thread is very old, but I just stumbled upon it a few days ago and I found a better solution in the mean time.

**Only applicable for Oracle DB:**

You could set this property:
*oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout*

According to Oracle's documentation, it represents: *read timeout while reading from the socket. This affects thin driver only. Timeout is in milliseconds.*

Documentation
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html

It's a little different than the Statement's implementation of the timeout, which results in a graceful stopping of the query, but in my case it was all that I needed.

Not sure if it cuts the connection though.. I'm using c3p0 , which does everything 'under the hood'.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old and about `PreparedStatement` timeout, but someone may still need the solution, and would be satisfied with one for the **whole `java.sql.Connection`**, e.g:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Connection connection = ...
connection.setNetworkTimeout(timeoutExecutor, config.timeout.toMillis.toInt);
```